# Can we find a natural norm smaller than the infinite norm for this special matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Let $\hat{\bf H}$ be a $p\hat{N}\times p \hat{N}$ sparse matrix consisting of $p\times p$ blocks, where each block is of size $\hat{N}\times\hat{N}$. The values in $\hat{\bf H}$ is illustrated below (empty places are zero):

> [image]

The infinite norm of $\hat{\bf H}$ is obviously 1, and I know infinite norm is no larger than any $p$-norm. **My question is**, is there an even smaller natural norm for this $\hat{\bf H}$?

---

The proof that infinite norm is no larger than any $p$-norm.

> [image]